# Can not click on tab when mouse listener has been added

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtabbedpane

I have been trying to add a pop up menu to the tab title of a JTabbedPane, which I have managed to do as follows:

```
        tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(a+2, x);


        x.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }


            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}


            private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    popUpMenuTab.show(e.getComponent(),
                               e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }

        });
```

However, with this if you right click you get the context menu, but if you left click nothing happnes. Does anyone know how I can get the orginal functionality back on the tab so that it changes to being active on a left click but also has the context menu on a right click.

An SSCCE is as follows

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class JTabbedPaneDemoextends JPanel {
    private JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

    public JTabbedPaneDemo() {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("java-swing-tutorial.JPG");
        JTabbedPane jtbExample = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel("Tab 1 Contains Tooltip and Icon");
        jtbExample.addTab("One", icon, jplInnerPanel1, "Tab 1");
        jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel("Tab 2 Contains Icon only");
        jtbExample.addTab("Two", icon, jplInnerPanel2);

        JPanel jplInnerPanel3  = createInnerPanel("Tab 3 Contains Tooltip and Icon");
        jtbExample.addTab("Three", icon, jplInnerPanel3, "Tab 3");

        JPanel jplInnerPanel4 = createInnerPanel("Tab 4 Contains Text only");
        jtbExample.addTab("Four", jplInnerPanel4);

        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 1"));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));

        JLabel tab4Label = new JLabel();
        tab4Label.setText("Four");  

        jtbExample.setTabComponentAt(3, tab4Label);


        tab4Label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }


            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}


            private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(),
                               e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }

        });


        //Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1)); 
        add(jtbExample);
    }

    protected JPanel createInnerPanel(String text) {
        JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel(text);
        jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
        return jplPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane Source Demo");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);}
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTabbedPaneDemo(), 
                                   BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 125);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here you can left click on tab 4 but you can't right click.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Not sure how to post on SSCCE

Comment: What you posted is not an SSCCE.  Which part of the linked document on the SSCCE are you having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Coincidentally, this answer uses the same approach as @Neifen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818752/can-not-click-on-tab-when-mouse-listener-has-been-added/7820254#7820254), but the example may be worth preserving.

Setting the tabbed pane model's selected index seems to work: `getModel().setSelectedIndex(3)`. I've updated your example to use the event dispatch thread and to be an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) by making it *self-contained*.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818752 */
public class JTabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {

    private JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();

    public JTabbedPaneDemo() {
        Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("html.pendingImage");
        final JTabbedPane jtb = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel("Tab 1: Tooltip and Icon");
        jtb.addTab("One", icon, jplInnerPanel1, "Tab 1");
        jtb.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel("Tab 2: Icon only");
        jtb.addTab("Two", icon, jplInnerPanel2);

        JPanel jplInnerPanel3 = createInnerPanel("Tab 3: Tooltip and Icon");
        jtb.addTab("Three", icon, jplInnerPanel3, "Tab 3");

        JPanel jplInnerPanel4 = createInnerPanel("Tab 4: Text only");
        jtb.addTab("Four", jplInnerPanel4);

        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 1"));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));

        JLabel tab4Label = new JLabel();
        tab4Label.setText("Four");
        jtb.setTabComponentAt(3, tab4Label);
        tab4Label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                jtb.getModel().setSelectedIndex(3);
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });

        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(jtb);
    }

    private JPanel createInnerPanel(String text) {
        JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel(text);
        jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
        return jplPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane Source Demo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JTabbedPaneDemo());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(400, 125);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tought than he would maybe want to make a popupmenu on every tab, thats why I made the Listener to an object. But both example are right I think.

Answer (score 3):

This is my Solution:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class JTabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {
    private JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    private JTabbedPane jtbExample;

    public JTabbedPaneDemo() {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("java-swing-tutorial.JPG");
        jtbExample = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel jplInnerPanel1 = createInnerPanel("Tab 1 Contains Tooltip and Icon");
        jtbExample.addTab("One", icon, jplInnerPanel1, "Tab 1");
        jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JPanel jplInnerPanel2 = createInnerPanel("Tab 2 Contains Icon only");
        jtbExample.addTab("Two", icon, jplInnerPanel2);

        JPanel jplInnerPanel3 = createInnerPanel("Tab 3 Contains Tooltip and Icon");
        jtbExample.addTab("Three", icon, jplInnerPanel3, "Tab 3");

        JPanel jplInnerPanel4 = createInnerPanel("Tab 4 Contains Text only");
        jtbExample.addTab("Four", jplInnerPanel4);

        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 1"));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));

        JLabel tab4Label = new JLabel();
        tab4Label.setText("Four");

        jtbExample.setTabComponentAt(3, tab4Label);

        tab4Label.addMouseListener(new TabbedMouseListener(3));

        // Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        add(jtbExample);
    }

    protected JPanel createInnerPanel(String text) {
        JPanel jplPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel jlbDisplay = new JLabel(text);
        jlbDisplay.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        jplPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        jplPanel.add(jlbDisplay);
        return jplPanel;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Mouselistener for the Tabbedpane
     * 
     */
    class TabbedMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private final int index;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param index
         *            the index of the tab
         */
        public TabbedMouseListener(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            maybeShowPopup(e);
        }

        private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
            else {
                jtbExample.setSelectedIndex(index);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane Source Demo");
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTabbedPaneDemo(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 125);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have made a the listener as a class. When you declare the listener you can put the index of the tab as parameter.
I also made the tabbedPane global

Comment: +1 for `MouseAdapter`. You might want to start on the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Feel free to clone my `UIManager` icon. I would urge the poster to accept this answer.

Comment: you mean something like: `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(.....` and then inside that: `JFrame frame= new Jframe...` ?

Comment: Yes; I did something similar in my variation's `main()`.